# scrollbox mouse wheel delphi

Tags: delphi, vcl

How to add `OnMouseWheel` to the same form for two scrollboxes? I applied the method to `ScrollBox1` but I did not know how to add the method to `ScrollBox2`

```
procedure TForm3.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  LTopLeft, LTopRight, LBottomLeft, LBottomRight: SmallInt;
  LPoint: TPoint;
begin
   inherited;
  LPoint := ScrollBox1.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));

  LTopLeft := LPoint.X;
  LTopRight := LTopLeft + ScrollBox1.Width;

  LBottomLeft := LPoint.Y;
  LBottomRight := LBottomLeft + ScrollBox1.Width;


  if (MousePos.X >= LTopLeft) and
    (MousePos.X <= LTopRight) and
    (MousePos.Y >= LBottomLeft)and
    (MousePos.Y <= LBottomRight) then
  begin
    ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position :=
    ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position - WheelDelta;

    Handled := True;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the same handler to both ScrollBox components, not to the Form, and then use the `Sender` parameter to know which component is calling the handler.

```
procedure TForm3.ScrollBoxMouseWheel(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  LTopLeft, LTopRight, LBottomLeft, LBottomRight: SmallInt;
  LPoint: TPoint;
  ScrollBox: TScrollBox;
begin
  ScrollBox := TScrollBox(Sender);
  LPoint := ScrollBox.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));
  LTopLeft := LPoint.X;
  LTopRight := LTopLeft + ScrollBox.ClientWidth;
  LBottomLeft := LPoint.Y;
  LBottomRight := LBottomLeft + ScrollBox.ClientWidth;
  if (MousePos.X >= LTopLeft) and
    (MousePos.X <= LTopRight) and
    (MousePos.Y >= LBottomLeft) and
    (MousePos.Y <= LBottomRight) then
  begin
    ScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Position := ScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Position - WheelDelta;
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, can you give me an example of what to do

Comment: You copied the code completely and did not work
Are there names to be assigned?

I have ScrollBox1 ,,,ScrollBox2

Comment: @Alhmam `repeat` *read again the text before the code* `until understood;` Then look carefully how the local variable `ScrollBox: TScrollBox;` is used. After this line: `ScrollBox := TScrollBox(Sender);`, `ScrollBox` refers to the actual scrollbox that triggered the event (either your `ScrollBox1` or `ScrollBox2`). Therefore the scrollbar position of the correct scrollbox is set. This is a typical example of why, and how to avoid direct references to the triggering control in an event handler.

Comment: @AlhmamAlhmam The `Sender` is what's important here. If user has their mouse pointed over `ScrollBox1` and scrolls the mouse wheel, then it will trigger this event and the `Sender` will point to `ScrollBox1`. The code within this event handler further does *not* directly reference any specific control, but instead works with whatever was passed as the `Sender` in the event handler. Simply assign this same event handler to any `TScrollBox` on your form, and it will automatically use this code for whatever scroll box the user is trying to scroll.

Comment: This code will only work if the ScrollBox has no controls in it. If it has, then the user won't be able to scroll once one of those controls came under the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Uses Math;

procedure TMainForm.ScrollBoxMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ScrollBox: TScrollBox;
  NewPos: Integer;
begin
  ScrollBox := TScrollBox(Sender);

  NewPos:= ScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Position - WheelDelta div 10;  // sensitivity
  NewPos:= Max(NewPos, 0);
  NewPos:= Min(NewPos, ScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Range);

  ScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Position := NewPos;
  Handled := True;
end;
```

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.